# Why doesn't my partial view render <tr> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I'm trying to create a table, where the table rows being divs that I've constructed from data that I get from my database.

I've seem to run into a issue.. I got this piece of javascript that starts running as soon as the page is ready, and it runs over and over again each 10 seconds. The purpose of this script is to update the partial view using ajax so that I don't have to refresh the browser to see changes in the table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(CheckAvailability, 10000);
        setTimeout
    });

    function CheckAvailability() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Dashboard/CheckChange",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            mimeType: "text/html",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    $('#itemsss').load("/Dashboard/ReturnItems");
                    console.log("Updated!");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Failed!");
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

This returns `true` every single time because it's something I've set explicitly.
It does `load();` the content that this action returns though.

```
public IActionResult ReturnItems()
{
    Items = new List<EbayProduct>();
    using (var ctx = new UserContext())
    {
        Items = ctx.Users.Include(x => x.Items).Where(x => x.Username == "Admin").FirstOrDefault().Items;
    }

    return PartialView("_Item", Items);
    //return null;
}
```

This is where I load the PartialView

```
<div id="itemsss">
    <table id="foo-filtering" class="table table-bordered table-hover toggle-circle" data-page-size="7">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <partial name="_Item" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div class="ft-right">
                        <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is what the actual PartialView looks like

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                <div class="container-1">
                    <div class="box-img">
                        <img src="@item.ProductImage" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="body">
                        <h3>@item.ItemName</h3>
                        <p>@item.SubTitle</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box-button">
                        <p>@item.SKU</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="box-button">
                        <p class="mt-3 mr-2">$@item.Price</p>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

And here is where the issue occurs.. When I first load the page, it all works fine, it looks great and it works perfectly, but as soon as it does the first refresh.. Or `.load();`.. It suddenly stops working correctly, and by that I mean that it doesn't load any `<tr>` elements.

This is what the DOM looks like when I first load the page and it hasn't refreshed yet, each `td` contains the div with the class `container-1` so it works just fine

[image]

And here is what it looks like after the first refresh and every single refresh after that
[image]

Comment: `<tr><td><partial name="_Item" /></td></tr>` would create invalid markup, based on your partial view, since you'd be embedding a `<tbody>` inside a `<td>`.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery call `$('#itemsss').load("/Dashboard/ReturnItems")` replaces existing content of the container with new elements - [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) states it as

> .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched elements to the returned data.

Replacing the `innerHTML` of `#itemsss` wipes out the table element. Because `<tbody>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` tags are invalid outside a table, the parser ignores them, leaving  `#itemsss` containing `<div`> elements only, as shown in the second picture.

If successful AJAX calls are intended to update the whole table the server could send complete HTML for the table, which could then be used to replace the content of `#itemss`, as shown in the post. Since picture 1 shows multiple `tbody` elements I assume this is not the case.

I tried appending `tbody` html to the table under different conditions: with or without a header and with or without existing table sections. Warning I am not a jQuery programmer - if useful, integrate and modify as best suited:

```js
"use strict";

function appendTableBody( bodyHTML) {
   let previous = $("#foo-filtering > tbody").last();
   if( !previous.length) {
       previous = $("#foo-table > thead").last();
   }
   if( previous.length) {    
       previous.after( bodyHTML);
   }
   else {
       $("#foo-filtering").prepend( bodyHTML)
   }
}
appendTableBody("<tbody><tr><td>appended section<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody>", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- body-html -->
<table id="foo-filtering">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Table Header</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Table section 1</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Table section 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><th>table footer</th></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I didn't try to replace an existing `tbody` element, but assume it would involve selecting the element and calling the [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) method.

Comment: That's very interesting! And it also makes a lot of sense to why it gets wiped out! I'm a bit confused about the `wrapping the response in suitable <table>/<table> tags before replying may be able to fix the issue.` part, would you be able to clairify that a bit?

Comment: @RileyVarga Backend changes are probably not needed or desirable, but it depends on the exact objective of table updates.  See the updated answer for discussion.

Comment: I just saw it, that looks very interesting! I find it strange to why my `.load("/Dashboard/ReturnItems")` wouldn't actually load in the table and what not, do you reckon it would if I tried putting the table in my partial views _Items?

Comment: I can tell you that it did not after testing it, it has multiple table tags with no `tr` elements

Comment: Do you reckon an approach like this would be smarter? Updating each item one by one https://stackoverflow.com/a/10874221/11966121